# Hide Navigation when webpage loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I open my webpage, the navigation bar (located in the footer), is already opened, while it should be hidden. It would show up if you click an icon and will hide again when clicked the same icon again.

The code is working because footer hiden and shows up when clicked on the icon, but the only thing that should be changed is that the footer should be hidden immediately when the webpage is loaded.

```js
var mijnKnop = document.getElementById("toggleMenu");
console.log(mijnKnop);

var mijnMenu = document.getElementById("navigatie");
console.log(mijnMenu);

var toggleStatus = 1;
console.log('status begin:' + toggleStatus);


mijnKnop.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('mijnknop click event');
  if (toggleStatus == 1) {
    console.log('status is 1');
    mijnMenu.style.display = "none";

    toggleStatus = 0;
  } else if (toggleStatus == 0) {
    console.log('status is 0');
    mijnMenu.style.display = "flex";

    toggleStatus = 1;
  }

});
```

```css
footer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 8vh;
  background-color: #ededed;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-family: 'Concert One', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #847d7d;
  margin: 0 100px 0 100px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="foto"></div>
<div id="toggleMenu"></div>

<footer id="navigatie">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Who are we</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">History</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
mijnMenu.style.display = "none";
```

after

```
 var mijnMenu = document.getElementById("navigatie");
```

and change this

```
if (toggleStatus == 1) {
      console.log('status is 1');
    mijnMenu.style.display = "none";

    toggleStatus = 0;
 }

else if (toggleStatus == 0) {
      console.log('status is 0');
    mijnMenu.style.display = "flex";

    toggleStatus = 1;
}
```

to this

```
if (toggleStatus == 1) {
                console.log('status is 1');
                mijnMenu.style.display = "flex";

                toggleStatus = 0;
            }

            else if (toggleStatus == 0) {
                console.log('status is 0');
                mijnMenu.style.display = "none";

                toggleStatus = 1;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set up the initial value of your footer to "display: none" :

```
<footer id="navigatie" style="display: none">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a general sense of "webpage getting loaded", then all you need to do is set the `display` of your `footer` element to `none` :-

```
<footer id="navigate" style="display: none;">
```

If you meant specifically "page load" i.e the event fired when page is loaded, add the following code to the end of your JavaScript:

```
addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('navigate').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Hope I helped :-)